# Docker PhantomJS 2 container is stopping suddenly

Tags: docker, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs docker container, latest version of wernight/phantomjs. Here is link. https://hub.docker.com/r/wernight/phantomjs/
The problem is; When I start the container, after some time (2-3 days)
container is stopping suddenly with below error. Anyone has any idea or suggestion ? I use exist container as is.

```
    ERROR - 2017-08-29T05:26:36.534Z] RouterReqHand - _handle.error -         
{"stack":"evaluateJavaScript@[native code]\nevaluate@phantomjs://platform/webpage.js:390:39\n_getTextCommand@phantomjs://code/webelement_request_handler.js:341:90\n_handle@phantomjs://code/webelement_request_handler.js:102:28\n_reroute@phantomjs://code/session_request_handler.js:61:20\n_handle@phantomjs://code/session_request_handler.js:120:42\n_reroute@phantomjs://code/request_handler.js:61:20\n_handle@phantomjs://code/router_request_handler.js:78:46","line":390,"sourceURL":"phantomjs://platform/webpage.js"}


phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
1   0x1b67967 phantomjs() [0x1b67967]
2   0x1b800a9 phantomjs() [0x1b800a9]
3   0x92035b phantomjs() [0x92035b]
4   0x13b9e20 phantomjs() [0x13b9e20]
5   0x13b9f2a phantomjs() [0x13b9f2a]
6   0x13bb9c1 phantomjs() [0x13bb9c1]
7   0x13bcaa4 phantomjs() [0x13bcaa4]
8   0x13bcb6c phantomjs() [0x13bcb6c]
9   0x97bf27 phantomjs() [0x97bf27]
10  0x77e64b phantomjs() [0x77e64b]
11  0x478dc4 phantomjs() [0x478dc4]
12  0x47ad10 phantomjs() [0x47ad10]
13  0x42d613 phantomjs() [0x42d613]
14  0x425e34 phantomjs() [0x425e34]
15  0x41b90c phantomjs() [0x41b90c]
16  0x46ba0b phantomjs() [0x46ba0b]
17  0x46c503 phantomjs() [0x46c503]
18  0x7b6cad phantomjs() [0x7b6cad]
19  0x17fd966 phantomjs() [0x17fd966]
20  0x19db06e phantomjs() [0x19db06e]
21  0x19e7b07 phantomjs() [0x19e7b07]
22  0x19eed55 phantomjs() [0x19eed55]
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
<http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html and file a bug report.
```

Comment: I suspect the process is running out of memory, I am intrigued to know what use case requires a phantomJS container to be running for multiple days?

Comment: we have scheduled service to parse some kind of website. For example every hour one time parse.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what is happening. You can run your container with `--restart=unless-stopped`. This will restart the container when it fails.

And since PhantomJS is no more maintained no one will answer your crash report on the forum. So best to just recover from the issue when it happens

Comment: Thanks Tarun, I will try '--restart-unless-stopped' option.